# Network Path not found while joining Active Directory

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

So I have an Amazon EC2 box running Windows Server 2008 with Active Directory installed on it. I also have a Windows 7 virtual machine, which is set to use the Active Directory box as its DNS and WINS server. I'm trying to join the virtual machine to the domain, and I'm asked for authentication. I give authentication, wait a minute, and I get an error saying:

```
The following error occurred attempting to join the domain "ad.chigs.me":

The network path was not found.
```

How can I fix this so that I'll be able to join the domain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problems like this are *always* due to DNS.

Try the following commands from the PC you are trying to join to the domain

```
nslookup ad
nslookup ad.chigs.me
```

They should both resolve if you've got everything configured correctly.

It would be beneficial if you would include the output of `ipconfig /all` and ip details for your domain controllers within your question.

Comment: These both resolve for me, but adding still results in the message in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Never tinkered with EC2, but my 2 cents,

From your Virtual client machine, do a `ping ad` or `ping ad.chigs.me`, if its able to ping, then it means that the server and client are reachable.

Also check the subnet and other network settings to ensure that they both are on the same network

Other issue being the `COnnection Specific DNS Suffix` and `DNS Suffic search order`

Comment: Ping is disabled on the box, but I know that they can talk to each other.

Comment: are you sure that ping is disabled?? I've experienced on x64 Win machines that you may have to open the command prompt in administrative mode to access some commands. (ipconfig and ping included )

Comment: @Chiggins `ping` disabled? Why? It's a diagnostic tool designed to help you resolve issues exactly like this. Disabling it serves no purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Just disable the second NIC, join the domain, and restart.  Then you can re-enable the other NIC.

Answer (score 0):

this has worked for me in XP not sure if it will on Win 7

try running the windows 7 VM in safe mode and then adding it to the domain.

regards

Comment: Tried that out, but sadly didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, even though DNS looked fine - rebooting the server fixed it. Here's the details:

- Server had dropped off domain
- Logged in as local admin, joined server to WORKGROUP
- Attempted to rejoin the domain (without rebooting) - error "Network Path was not found"
- `IPCONFIG /ALL` showed a valid DNS server
- `ping domain.local` OK
- `NSLOOKUP domain.local` OK
- Rebooted and was able to join the domain with no issues

Answer (score 0):

check port 445, it shoudnt be blocked on AD.

Comment: I'm sure the OP and future readers would appreciate an expansion of your thinking around this answer.

Comment: This is too short to be understood correctly.

Answer (score -1):

This is an old post but I've come across it a few times. IPV6 can cause problems in the DNS if not configured correctly. Disable it in the NIC, try again and change setting permanently.